# Multiple Charts on Single Excel Worksheet Forces Save on Every Close

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

## Problem

With two charts, the "Want to save your changes?" dialogue box pops up every single time I try to close the file. With one chart, the dialogue pops up the first time I close the file, but not on subsequent open and closes.

**How can I avoid this dialogue while still having two or more x-y scatter plots on the same worksheet?**

If that's impossible, can someone at least explain why this behavior exists?

I'm running Excel 2013 32-bit (15.0.4841.1000), if that makes any difference.

## Steps to replicate

1. Download my example file at https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak4Lq2gGjO8hkPxiiqVaRqzQojpfig.

   - Or if you'd prefer not to use my file, start a new blank workbook in Excel.
   - Create three columns of data. I'll refer to them as X, Y, and Z.
   - With the data, make an XY scatter plot and an XZ scatter plot.
   - Manually save the file.
2. Close the file, and notice you have to confirm "Save" in a  "Want to save your changes?" dialogue.
3. Re-open the file and immediately close it. Notice the dialogue pops up again.
4. Re-open the file and delete either one of the charts. Close it, and notice the dialogue pops up again (even if you manually save it before closing).
5. Re-open the file and immediately close it. There's no dialogue box this time; somehow Excel realized there's been no changes.

**Notes**

- This even happens with two of the *same* chart. Instead of creating an XY and an XZ chart, create an XY chart and copy-paste it. The problem still exists.
- This does not happen if the charts are on different worksheets. If the XZ and XY charts are in separate tabs, the file will save and close normally. This is not a solution, however, as I need both charts on the same worksheet (my actual file will be organized 10+ tabs, and I don't want to double that).

## Things I've tried

- Disabling automatic calculation in the workbook (Formulas → Calculation → Calculation Options → Manual). Since this does not solve it, I assume volatile functions have nothing to do with this.
- Rebooting.
- Google (and Bing)

Comment: Whenever a change occur to the worksheet it will ask to be saved on closing, check what is modifying your sheet automatically or by you without noticing it

Comment: If you are using a random formula to write your values under Y and Z it will change the values every time you open the file and Excel will ask for save because the values changed

Comment: I am creating the values with `=LN(A1)` and `=LOG(A1)`, but I have the same problem even when using hard-coded values. What changes can occur between me manually saving the file and closing it? Are charts inherently volatile for some reason?

Comment: Excel 2016 doesn't prompt me to save the file, unless I've made changes to it. I didn't expect it to, nor do I expect any of the other versions to.

Comment: Strange... It doesn't seem to happen on my home desktop, which is running Excel 2016 32-bit (16.0.6701.1036), but it does happen on my home laptop, which is running Excel 2013 32-bit (15.0. **4849**.1000). The original issue was on my work computer. It sounds like maybe this is a bug in Microsoft's software, that is now resolved in Office 2016.